# Proof of convergent function

Tags: limits, functions, epsilon-delta

Im asked to prove that the function
$$
{a_{n}}={{5n+3}\over{8n+9}}
$$

is convergent and find the limit $L$, obviously being $5\over8$
I have to use the definition of a limit
$$
\epsilon>0 \ \ \ \exists \ \ N>0 \ \ \ \ s.t \ \ \ \ \ n\ge N \ \Rightarrow \ |a_{n}-L|<\epsilon
$$
I've tried a bunch of different stuff I knew wasn't going to work. I think I have to get $n$ in terms of $\epsilon$ to show that for every $\epsilon$ there is an $n$ in that range but I'm not quite sure how to go about doing that.

Answer (score 1):

For every $\varepsilon > 0$ we have
$$
\bigg| \frac{5n+3}{8n+9} - \frac{5}{8} \bigg| = \frac{21}{64n + 72} <  \frac{21}{64n} < \varepsilon
$$
if $n \geq \lceil \frac{21}{64\varepsilon} \rceil$.

Comment: Yea thats what I got, for some reason I always think I have insufficient answer. Thanks again.

Comment: No problem; next time you may also post your whole argument along with the question, so that people can help you detect the wrongs.